# Beautiful Soup returns only javaScript Code?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to scrape data from the following website. https://dell.secure.force.com/FAP/?c=de&l=de&pt=findareseller
I tried to get data from the network tab but it returns nothing. Then I tried BeautifulSoup to get some data but it returns only Javascript with empty tbody tags. But in inspect element, it shows the data in a table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://dell.secure.force.com/FAP'
headers = {
   'Connection': 'keep-alive'
   }
data = {
'pt': "findareseller"
   }
page = requests.get(url, params= data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('table') # returns only javascript code.
```

Can someone help, how can I scrape the data?

Comment: Which data are you trying to scrape? Company names? Please add an example output to your question

Comment: Yes company names. Would like to have json() data. that may have company name, description, location etc

Comment: The data you want appears to be returned in a POST to `https://dell.secure.force.com/FAP/FAP_PartnerSearch` but the post data request looks too complicated to replicate

Comment: yeah, I have come so close. with this  after using post.                                                    st = soup.find('input')['value']

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all('table')` returns a list with all table elements.

So to find your specific element you should try to find some distinct properties that makes it different from all the other tables (like an id or class).

To access the elements attributes use `t[0].attrs` to get a list of them and for example: `t[0]["width"]` to access them.

Also: By using `soup.select('table')` instead, you can use css selectors as the string input, so you won't have to deal with beautifulsoups functions.

Comment: soup.find_all('table') only returns javascript code. there is no actual data. for example if you visit website, the first <tr> have company Named "ATOS TTS Resell DE". if you search in whole soup object, there is no such data.

Comment: the find_all function returns a list dude. You perhaps tried to print the result or something. The console output would have been the html of the element then, if you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
I figure out the answer.
I use network search to fetch any search requests. I found the search URL, to confirm if the URL was right, I double-clicked it and it returns the exact same page. so I copy the bash code and past it into POSTMAN as import "RAW TEXT". I find out it actually uses post requests. After using post request, I was able to fetch the data I needed.
below is the request with POST.

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

then I use BeautifulSoup as soup.

```
st = soup.find('input')['value'] # returns data I needed
```